# Contradiction and existence

Tags: logic, epistemology

I would have liked to know if this argument was logical and if it had already been made:

> Everything exists. The principle of non-contradiction applied to existence is a postulate that does not hold. Everything that is possible exists; the question then concerns the modalities of existence. When you say that a single married person does not exist, you are merging two concepts (celibacy + marriage) and judge that the product of the two (X) is impossible because it is contradictory. It is thus that X exists, otherwise there is nothing contradictory because there is nothing to judge. You can argue that the contradiction prevents manifestation, on the other hand, which is more defensible. It exists because you talk about it, but it is a non-manifestable possibility, like a round square. You are pointing to something when you say (improperly) that it is "impossible". Saying that X is Y, Y being "contradictory" or "inconceivable" for example, is necessarily presupposing the existence of X. The question will then concern its mode of existence. If X does not exist, what is contradictory? What is inconceivable? Nothing.

Comment: It has been made and is very old, Quine nicknamed it [Plato's beard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_beard):"*Nonbeing must in some sense be, otherwise what is it that there is not?*" See also [SEP, Nonexistent Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects/) for different ways of making sense of "some sense".

Comment: Do you mean non-existent objects do not exist?

Comment: There is a chapter on ths subject in Priest's Very Short Introducion To Logic.